# Strange Issue on Andengine when using android layout with LayoutBaseGameActivity?

Tags: java, android, andengine

i am using andengine in my application for animation.
when i am using a sprite click event then it gives strange issue.
i am using this sprite to hide show a view in android native layout.

my logcat output

```
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 3832
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 42, size is 42
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1382)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:260)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1160)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:627)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:617)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
        04-01 18:21:43.966: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

i dont know why it is causing please help

EDIT:

```
 04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899): FirstBaseActivity.onDestroy @(Thread: 'main')
        04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
        04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899): org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
        04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.throwOnDestroyed(Engine.java:574)
        04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:560)
        04-01 18:53:01.420: D/AndEngine(2899):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
        04-01 18:53:01.427: D/AndEngine(2899): FirstBaseActivity.onDestroyResources @(Thread: 'main')
        04-01 18:53:01.427: D/AndEngine(2899): FirstBaseActivity.onGameDestroyed @(Thread: 'main')
```

full logcat

Comment: from the trace its look like array index problem. Not sure where the problem is. Can you paste complete stack trace

Comment: @Real here is full logcat

Comment: Hi @SuperUser, it is tough for me to identify the problem I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the scene graph from thread different than the `UpdateThread`. Maybe from some touch/sensor event. If you do so you have to dispatch to the `UpdateThread` via `runOnUpdateThread(Runnable)`.